# How to json_encode complex data structures in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I've got a data structure which at the top level is a dictionary, and contains lists.  A typical example might be:

```
array('foo' => array(1, 2, 3),
      'bar' => array(4, 5, 6));
```

The top-level dictionary might have no attributes, and the inner lists might be empty.

These structures need to be JSON-encoded.  The problem is that PHP doesn't differentiate between an empty dictionary and an empty list, so it doesn't know if array() should be rendered as '{}' or '[]'.  I can force '{}' by doing

```
json_encode($object, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

but that renders

```
array('foo' => array());
```

as '{"foo": {}}', when it should be '{"foo": []}'.  If I leave out the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT, then

```
array();
```

gets rendered as '[]', when it should be '{}'.  What's the solution, other than chucking PHP and writing this in a sane language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through your data and replace all the array()s that should be objects with

```
$objectItem = new stdClass();
```

or do

```
$objectItem = (object)$objectItem;
```

Alternatively, you can just use objects from the start for those items instead of arrays.